# Back button from Thank you page

Tags: back-button

User has just completed a purchase of the insurance product and he has gotten a Thank you page.

Now he clicks browser's Back button. What is the best practice?

- block an back button action and stays on the Thank you page
- error page with explanation
- bring user to step 1 of buying the same insurance product
- bring user to home page of all insurance products available
- bring him at the website homepage

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83340/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-browser-back-navigation-on-checkout). It handles the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide the user with a page that asks him if he has some problems or made a mistake while purchasing, add a contact form which enables the user to address his issue, for example "wrong address" or "wrong phone number".

If i would have to choose from your options i would go with:
- bring user to step 1 of buying the same insurance product